# How to gain the write permission when I use Macro to open a xls file

Tags: excel, csv, vba

```
Sub test()
Dim objXL
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim UpdateLinks As Variant
Dim ReadOnly As Variant
With objXL
    .Workbooks.Open(FileName:= "test.xls",UpdateLinks:=0,ReadOnly:=False)
    .Visible = True
End With
Set objXL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the code I used to open an Excel file in Macro, but it reported a syntax error in the 8th line with Workbooks.Open() function. I tried but could not figure out where I got wrong. More information about Workbooks.Open() function can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `()` in a method call (unless you are assigning the result). Use

```
.Workbooks.Open(FileName:= "test.xls",UpdateLinks:=0,ReadOnly:=False)
```

That said, why are you you creating an application object? If this is coded in *Excel* this works

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="test.xls", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False)
```

or just

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:="test.xls", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False
```

Although it is better to specify the full path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

`.Workbooks.Open FileName:="test.xls", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False`